# how to display geometry format data in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, geojson

Sorry my english is not good.
I have problem with to display data format "geometry" from mysql database. I got the data from file extension .geojson (like json but but contains coordinate), I convert the .geojson data with cmd. and this data is formed.

for example my geojson data 
[image]

and this is an example of converting geojson to database

[image]
[image]

i use laravel, to display this data what is the task of laravel or mysql (eg there is a special mysql function)? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking to do with the geometry data and have you looked at the Geo JSON functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html such as St+GeomFromJson()??

Comment: thanks @Dave Stokes for answer. I try in my PhpMyadmin but errors.
my query 
"SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11.11111 12.22222)'),2)"
and my error FUNCTION ST_AsGeoJSON does not exist. 

is it related to the mysql version?

Comment: now I find my error, related to the issue of the mysql version that I am using. Thankyou verymuch @Dave Stokes

Comment: Can you show how to show the geometry values of a specific row?